# Consulta con datos agrupados por tiempo tanto si existe como si no

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Actualmente tengo que hacer un informe en función de una consulta, la consulta que se hace debe devolver todos los paros que ha habido en un rango de fechas determinadas cada cinco minutos, si existe un registro que cumpla dicha condición para ese intervalo deberia devolver 1, y si no existe ningun registro, deberia devolver 0.
Para explicarlo un poco mas sencillo pongo una imagen de la tabla ejemplo:
(*No deja subir imagen asi que pongo link debajo)
[imagen de la tabla ejemplo](http://subefotos.com/ver/?013392cef68f075a4967036d4d72aebbo.png)
Lo que necesito es que tras la consulta me devuelva 0 para el intervalo 00:00 - 00:05, 00:05 - 00:10, .... , y que para 06:05 - 06:10 devuelta 1 y asi con esta logica todos los intervalos entre determinadas fechas.

Para lograrlo he encontrado algo de ayuda:

```
select variable,
   convert(varchar(8), tiempo, 1)+' '
  +convert(varchar(2), datepart(hh, tiempo))+':'
  +convert(varchar(2), datepart(mi, tiempo)/5),
  count(*) 
  from datos group by 
  variable,
  convert(varchar(8), tiempo, 1)+' '
  +convert(varchar(2), datepart(hh, tiempo))+':'
  +convert(varchar(2), datepart(mi, tiempo)/5)
```

El problema es que este codigo si me muestra los intervalos en los que existen registros pero no en los que no existen.
Estoy trabajando contra un MSSQL Server 2012
Un saludo.

Comment: La consulta tiene o podría tener un límite? Por ejemplo: "Siempre se consultará un mes entero y no más de un mes?

Comment: Si, en principio seria un dia entero o desde las 06:00 de un dia hasta las  05:59 del siguiente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este es un problema bastante recurrente, el de generar registros dónde no los hay. En tu caso necesitarías armar de antemano los períodos de tiempo para determinar si en los mismos hay o no lecturas. Como has comentado que trabajas con un máximo de 24 horas que serían 288 (26 * 60 / 5) períodos, es factible usar la solución que te propongo, y que se basa en generar una tabla dinámica de intervalos de tiempos a partir de una fecha inicial. Con esta tabla podremos hacer un `LEFT JOIN` con `datos` y dónde no haya registros contaremos como 0 la cantidad.

Veamos:

```
DECLARE @Datos TABLE (
    Variable VARCHAR(15),
    Tiempo   DATETIME
)

DECLARE @Intervalos TABLE (
    Nro     INT,
    Desde   DATETIME,
    Hasta   DATETIME
)

DECLARE @PrimerIntervalo DATETIME

INSERT INTO @Datos (Variable, Tiempo)
VALUES  ('TAG_1', '20170807 10:00:01 am'),
    ('TAG_1', '20170807 10:04:01 am'),
    ('TAG_1', '20170807 10:11:01 am'),
    ('TAG_1', '20170807 10:12:01 am'),
    ('TAG_1', '20170807 10:25:01 am')

SELECT  @PrimerIntervalo    = '20170807 09:30:00 am'

-- CREAMOS UNA TABLA DE INTERVALOS DE 24 HORAS 
INSERT INTO @Intervalos(Nro)
SELECT  (T1.NRO-1)*100 + (T2.NRO-1)*10 + T3.NRO
    FROM ( SELECT 1 AS 'NRO' UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 ) T1 
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 1 AS 'NRO' UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 ) T2
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT 1 AS 'NRO' UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 ) T3
    WHERE (T1.NRO-1)*100 + (T2.NRO-1)*10 + T3.NRO <= (24 * 60) / 5
    ORDER BY T1.NRO,T2.NRO,T3.NRO

UPDATE  @Intervalos
    SET Desde = DATEADD(Mi, (Nro - 1) * 5, @PrimerIntervalo),
            Hasta = DATEADD(Mi, Nro * 5, @PrimerIntervalo)

-- CONSULTA FINAL
SELECT  V.Variable,
    CONVERT(CHAR(5), I.Desde, 108)  AS 'Desde',
    CONVERT(CHAR(5), I.Hasta, 108)  AS 'Hasta',
    ISNULL(COUNT(D.Tiempo),0)       AS 'Cantidad'
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Variable AS Variable
            FROM @Datos
        ) V
    LEFT JOIN @Intervalos I
        ON 1 = 1
    LEFT JOIN @Datos D
        ON D.Tiempo >= I.Desde
        AND D.Tiempo < I.Hasta
        AND D.Variable = V.Variable
        AND D.Tiempo BETWEEN @PrimerIntervalo AND DATEADD(HH, 24, @PrimerIntervalo)
    GROUP BY V.Variable,
        I.Nro, 
        I.Desde,
        I.Hasta
    ORDER BY Nro
```

La primer parte no tiene mucho misterio, creamos una tabla tipo variable, (podría ser una temporal también) para un ejemplo de lo que sería tu tabla `datos` y de una nueva que llamaremos `Intervalos`. Luego establecemos el valor de una variable `@PrimerIntervalo` que representará desde dónde haremos la consulta sobre `datos`. Como ejemplo `SELECT  @PrimerIntervalo    = '20170807 09:30:00 am'` nuestra consulta comenzará el el 7/8  a las 9.30.

Luego completamos `Intervalos` con uno de los posibles métodos para generar secuencias o intervalos que podemos usar en SQL Server, hay mejores formas en cuanto a performance pero la que te muestro es bastante sencilla de entender, son unos `CROSS JOINS` de tres tablas con 10 registros cada una lo que nos permitirá generar una única tabla con 1000 registros (10 x 10 x 10), numerados del 1 al 1000, de la que solo usaremos 288 para generar los intervalos. Te sugiero [este](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) excelente articulo sobre como generar secuencias en SQL server por si quieres profundizar en el tema.

Para terminar con esta etapa, simplemente generamos los campos Desde / Hasta sumando 5 minutos a la fecha de `@PrimerIntervalo` por `Nro` de `Intervalos`, lo cual nos dejaría algo así:

```
Nro     Desde                       Hasta  
======= =========================== =========================
1,00    07/08/2017 09:30:00 a.m.    07/08/2017 09:35:00 a.m.
2,00    07/08/2017 09:35:00 a.m.    07/08/2017 09:40:00 a.m.
3,00    07/08/2017 09:40:00 a.m.    07/08/2017 09:45:00 a.m.
....
```

Esto ya nos da una pauta de lo que vamos a terminar haciendo: "cruzar" estos periodos/intervalos con `datos` si en uno no tenemos registros lo contaremos como 0.

Y por último esta consulta:

```
-- CONSULTA FINAL
SELECT  V.Variable,
    CONVERT(CHAR(5), I.Desde, 108)  AS 'Desde',
    CONVERT(CHAR(5), I.Hasta, 108)  AS 'Hasta',
    ISNULL(COUNT(D.Tiempo),0)       AS 'Cantidad'
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Variable AS Variable
            FROM @Datos
            WHERE Tiempo BETWEEN @PrimerIntervalo AND DATEADD(HH, 24, @PrimerIntervalo)
        ) V
    LEFT JOIN @Intervalos I
        ON 1 = 1
    LEFT JOIN @Datos D
        ON D.Tiempo >= I.Desde
        AND D.Tiempo < I.Hasta
        AND D.Variable = V.Variable
        AND D.Tiempo BETWEEN @PrimerIntervalo AND DATEADD(HH, 24, @PrimerIntervalo)
    GROUP BY V.Variable,
        I.Nro, 
        I.Desde,
        I.Hasta
    ORDER BY Nro
```

Que verifica cada Variable distinta que tengas en las 24 horas solicitadas y por cada uno de los 288 intervalos de tiempo, la salida es algo así:

```
Variable  Desde Hasta   Cantidad
========= ===== =====   ========
TAG_1     09:45 09:50   0,00
TAG_1     09:50 09:55   0,00
TAG_1     09:55 10:00   0,00
TAG_1     10:00 10:05   2,00
TAG_1     10:05 10:10   0,00
TAG_1     10:10 10:15   2,00
TAG_1     10:15 10:20   0,00
TAG_1     10:20 10:25   0,00
TAG_1     10:25 10:30   1,00
TAG_1     10:30 10:35   0,00
...
```

Comment: Gracias, muy buena respuesta, una pena que no se pueda hacer de una manera mas sencilla.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo he entendido bien, deberías pintar todos los rangos de 5 minutos de un día (según lo que has dicho, serian 288 lineas) y que en función de si existe un valor en la tabla datos, te pinte un 0 o un 1 verdad?

Si es así, creo que no se podrá hacer mediante únicamente una consulta. Ya que no puedes pintar valores que no existen en la tabla, deberías tener un `for` o alguna estructura de control para iterar sobre esos 288 rangos de 5 minutos que tiene un día e ir consultando en cada vuelta si existe un valor en la tabla para saber si pintar un 1 o un 0

Para hacer eso tendrías que usar [procedimientos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms345415(v=sql.120).aspx), la parte mala que le veo a esto, es que tendrías que lanzar 288 consultas (una para cada rango) y eso podría sobrecargar un poco la BD.

Comment: Hola, el campo que definiria si se pone 1 o 0 es si existe algun registro en ese intervalo, es decir en el resultado de la consulta me aparecen los casos que deberia poner 1, pero necesito tambien los casos en los que serian 0. es decir la consulta me deberia devolver 24 horas + 60 minutos / 5minutos del rango = 288 registros con valor 0 o 1 en funcion de su hay algun paro en el rango correspondiente. Espero haberme explicado mejor ahora.

Comment: ahh, ok, voy a ver si alguien tiene una "idea feliz" y se le ocurre alguna manera de hacerlo en una consulta. gracias